# Freemarker Out of memory

Tags: freemarker

I'm using springboot+freemarker.
Customer can modify the freemarker template.
If you add `<#assign x><#list 1..9999999999999 as n>${n}</#list></#assign>${x}`
The backend will throw out of memory error.
Is there any solution that can define the memory of the template.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html) currently has no support/solution for it:

> It's trivial to create templates that run practically forever (with a loop), or exhaust memory (by concatenating to a string in a loop). FreeMarker can't enforce CPU or memory usage limits, so this is something that has no solution on the FreeMarker-level.

You shouldn't blindly let customer handle freemarker templates

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the security implications. FreeMarker templates can call the public methods of the objects you put into the data-model. See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_template_uploading_security

If your user can't be trusted (and held accountable), you can't allow them to specify FreeMarker templates.

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the memory used for your application (not specifically for the template), using [Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm) option.

For example:

```
java -Xmx20G -jar app.jar
```

would start app.jar with 20Gb of memory.

Unfortunately there is little chance that your template will work, as it tries to create a string with 10000 billion elements (1e13 elements), which would take at least 10 terabytes of memory. I'm not even sure that Java can deal with strings this size.